# Sql Case expression in JPA criteria update

Tags: sql, jpa, case, criteria-api

I have a named query :

```
"UPDATE student SET student.marks = " +
"    CASE WHEN student.name in :" + nameListOne + 
"         THEN 10 ELSE marks " + 
"     END  , student.class = 6 WHERE student.name in :" +  namelistOneAndTwo
```

how can i achieve this using criteria update.
This is just a example i want to understand how case expression can be used in criteria update.

Comment: Also, please tag your DBMS

Comment: question is for jpa criteriaUpdate.

Comment: so tell people what you have tried, and which part you have problem in creating in Criteria ... (and fix the typo in your question in "sudent")

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier just to have two updates. Not sure what "nameListOne" is, I'm assuming this is some parameter in a dynamic SQL query string.

```
UPDATE student 
   SET marks = 10
 WHERE name IN nameListOne;

UPDATE student
   SET class = 6
 WHERE name IN nameListOneAndTwo;
```

There's some value in keeping things simple and intuitive.

Comment: question is for criteriaUpdate. How can we achieve mentioned jpa named query in  criteriaUpdate.

Comment: To be fair, the question was explained by a JPQL statement so the answer by @Error_2646 was also specified by JPQL. His idea is still valid though it does not really answer how to do a CASE with criteria API. But I would not have downvoted a constructive answer that helps to solve the concrete problem given with the query specified in the question...